# Single word CAS tagged pointer for algorithms susceptible to the ABA problem

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, thread-safety

I've been looking for a solution to the ABA problem for a lock-free stack. Searching the Web revealed patented and complicated hazard pointers and tagged pointers using double compare-and-swap (DCAS, CAS2). I would settle for the DCAS, but it's not available on some older AMD CPUs. So I came up with this helper class:

```
class TaggedPtrBase {
    typedef unsigned int tag_t;
    static const tag_t INVALIDATED = 1;
public:
    TaggedPtrBase() {
        tag.store(0, std::memory_order_relaxed);
        ptr = 0;
    }
    TaggedPtrBase & operator=(const TaggedPtrBase & other) {
        tag.store(other.tag.load(std::memory_order_acquire), std::memory_order_relaxed);
        ptr = other.ptr;
        return *this;
    }
    operator void *() const {
        return get();
    }
    void * get() const {
        return ptr;
    }
    bool compare_and_swap(const TaggedPtrBase & oldval, void * newptr) {
        uintptr_t old_tag = oldval.tag.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
        if (old_tag & INVALIDATED) {
            return false;
        }
        if (tag.compare_exchange_strong(old_tag, old_tag | INVALIDATED, std::memory_order_acquire)) {
            ptr = newptr;
            tag.store(old_tag + 2, std::memory_order_release);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
private:
    std::atomic<tag_t> tag;
    void * ptr;
};
...
void push(Node * node) {
    void * newptr = reinterpret_cast<void *>(node);
    TaggedPtrBase old;
    do {
        old = ptr;
        node->next = static_cast<Node *>(old.get());
    } while (!ptr.compare_and_swap(old, newptr));
}
```

It appears to be working, but it's simplicity suggests that I'm missing something.
So I wonder if this is a proper solution, or is it just a glorified spin-lock? Any issues on non-x86 platforms?

Comment: How important is portability?  On current x86-64 platforms, pointers only have 48-significant bits.  You can play bit tricks to store a tag in the remaining (upper) 16 bits, and so use only a 64-bit (single word) compare-and-swap.  16 bits of tag don't give quite the safety against ABA that 64 bits of tag do, as it's possible to quickly overflow a 16 bit tag.  But it's still not particularly likely.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a spin lock. If the thread that invalidated of the tag got suspended right after, no other thread can make progress till the thread is resumed and releases the tag.

```
if (old_tag & INVALIDATED) {
    return false; // no thread can go further if ...
}
if (tag.compare_exchange_strong(old_tag, old_tag | INVALIDATED, 
                                std::memory_order_acquire)) {
    ptr = newptr; // <-- ... a thread is preempted here
    tag.store(old_tag + 2, std::memory_order_release);
    return true;
}
```

So the solution is not lock-free.